# RadListView drag and drop - Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have been working on this issue for a month now but can't seem to solve it. I am trying to drag an item from RadListView1 to RadListView2. I don't actually want to move or copy this item to RadListView2. I want to combine the item with an item that I am over when I release the mouse button over RadListView2 and display it in a RadListView3. Example. Drag a song name over to a singer and it combine the singer and songname into the RadListView3.

I just can't figure out the drag events and how to get the item I dragged to in RadListView2. Hopefully I didn't confuse the heck out of you.

Any help appreciated. I've looked at the Telerik docs forever but can't get it.

Thanks.

I can't even get this to work

```
 private void DragDropService_PreviewDragOver(object sender, RadDragOverEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanDrop = e.HitTarget is DetailListViewDataCellElement || e.HitTarget is DetailListViewElement;
        Debug.WriteLine("PreviewDragOver triggered");
    }
    private void DragDropService_PreviewDragDrop(object sender, RadDropEventArgs e)
    {
        BaseListViewVisualItem draggedItem = e.DragInstance as BaseListViewVisualItem;
        DetailListViewDataCellElement cellElement = e.HitTarget as DetailListViewDataCellElement;
        DetailListViewElement viewElement = e.HitTarget as DetailListViewElement;

        if (cellElement == null && viewElement == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("All NULL...returning");
            return;
        }
        e.Handled = true;

        if (viewElement != null) Debug.WriteLine("Over ViewElement");

        if (cellElement != null) Debug.WriteLine("Over cellElement");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/listview/drag-and-drop/drag-and-drop-using-raddragdropservice), in the **PreviewDragDrop** event, you have the **DragInstance** and the **HitTarget**.

Comment: Thanks checho. I have looked at that for many days. I updated the initial question to include some code that don't trigger at all.

Comment: What doesn't trigger, the events? Check your subscriptions.